# Need help with sequential element being partly removed from the module even if I am using completely

Tags: verilog, vivado

I have a simple module that split rows between different engines. In this module row_start_r is a register that is a counter that skips the count by a specified offset and eventually gets written in a FIFO. The following code works in simualtion but not on the actual FPGA.

The only thing suspicious in the synthesis report is that the tool sets the lower bits of row_start_r register to 0 and gives the following warning

```
 INFO: propagating constant 0 across sequential element (i_13/\LOAD_BALANCER/row_start_reg_reg[0]
 INFO: propagating constant 0 across sequential element (i_13/\LOAD_BALANCER/row_start_reg_reg[1] )
 INFO:  propagating constant 0 across sequential element(i_13/\LOAD_BALANCER/row_start_reg_reg[2] )
```

Following is my code.

```
`timescale 1 ns / 1 ps

module split_rows #(
     parameter NUM_ENGINES               = 2
)(
   input  wire                  clk,
   input  wire                  rst,
   output wire                  done,
   input  wire [63:0]           num_rows,
   output wire                  ready_out,
   input  wire [NUM_ENGINES-1:0] engine_ready_in,
   output   [63:0]              start_row_pos_out,
   output   [63:0]              end_row_pos_out,
   output  [NUM_ENGINES-1:0] engine_select_wr_out

);
reg [2:0]                  engine_id; /// num_engines
wire                       fifo_empty_s;
wire                       fifo_full_s;
reg                        fifo_rd_en;
wire                       fifo_wr_en;
reg [NUM_ENGINES-1:0]      engine_select_s;

reg  [63:0]              row_start_r;
wire [63:0]                row_start_out;
reg  [63:0]             start_row_pos_out_s;
wire [63:0]             end_row_pos_out_s;

always @(posedge clk)
 begin
  if (rst == 1'd1)           engine_id <= 3'd0;
  else if (engine_id ==  NUM_ENGINES-1) engine_id <= 3'd0;
  else                       engine_id <= engine_id + 3'd1;
end
always @(posedge clk)
begin
        if(rst) begin
                row_start_r <= 64'd0;
        end
        else if (fifo_wr_en) begin
                row_start_r <= row_start_r + 64'd32; //skip_offset ;
        end
end
assign fifo_wr_en = !rst && !fifo_full_s && (row_start_r < num_rows);

fifo #(.DEPTH(64), .WIDTH(64), .AFULLCNT(60), .RAM_STYLE("block") ) offset_holder (
    .clk    (clk),
    .reset  (rst),
    .push   (fifo_wr_en),
    .din    (row_start_r),
    .afull  (fifo_full_s),
    .full   (),
    .cnt    (),
    .oclk   (clk),
    .pop    (fifo_rd_en), // from write engine
    .dout   (row_start_out),
    .empty  (fifo_empty_s),
    .rcnt   ()
   );

always @(*)
   begin
      engine_select_s = 0;
      fifo_rd_en      = 0;
      start_row_pos_out_s = 64'd0;
      if ( !rst &&  engine_ready_in[engine_id] == 1  && !fifo_empty_s  )
      begin
         engine_select_s[engine_id] = 1;
         fifo_rd_en = 1;
         start_row_pos_out_s = row_start_out;
      end
end
 assign end_row_pos_out_s = (start_row_pos_out_s + 64'd32 >= num_rows) ? num_rows: row_start_out + 64'd32;
     assign ready_out            =  !rst && !fifo_empty_s;

assign start_row_pos_out        =  start_row_pos_out_s;
assign end_row_pos_out          =  end_row_pos_out_s  ;
assign engine_select_wr_out     =  engine_select_s    ;

done_stall #(
      .LENGTH                 (4)
   ) DONE_OUT (
      .clk                    (clk),
      .rst                    (rst),
      .done_in                (fifo_empty_s),
      .done_out               (done)
   );
endmodule
```

If somebody can review it and point out the mistake that would be really helpful.Thank you.

Comment: Please ask an actual specific question, also, this is not a code checking service

Comment: So my question is what is making register row_start_r being initialized to zero during the synthesis. I feel it is being properly initialized and used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is completely expected.

In your code for `row_start_r`, you do:

```
always @(posedge clk)
begin
        if(rst) begin
                row_start_r <= 64'd0;
        end
        else if (fifo_wr_en) begin
                row_start_r <= row_start_r + 64'd32; //skip_offset ;
        end
end
```

So you set it to 0 during reset, that's fine. Then when not in reset, each cycle you add on 32 (`64'b0100000`) when `fifo_wr_en` is high. Also fine.

However in all of this, look at the lower 5 bits. They are initially set to 0, and then you either add 0 to them, or let them keep the same value. Never will they be set to anything other than 0, so the synthesiser will optimise them away.

Removing these bits will not affect the behaviour of what you described, it is simply the least resource consuming way of achieving your requirement - after all, that's what the synthesizer is there to do, optimise.

Comment: Yea that makes sense. However I dont see this register mentioned in the Component infor. I get the following:     
`code`
Module split_rows__4

Detailed RTL Component Info :

+---Adders :
           2 Input     64 Bit       Adders := 2
           2 Input      3 Bit       Adders := 1

+---Registers :
                      ** 3 Bit    Registers := 1**
+---Muxes :
           2 Input     64 Bit        Muxes := 1
           2 Input      3 Bit        Muxes := 1